# Typescript how to use ArrayBuffer data made of JSON

Tags: node.js, typescript, websocket, buffer, arraybuffer

I am receiving ArrayBuffer data from a server via Websocket, and having a trouble converting the incoming data into other form.

Here's the code for the WebSocket:

```
let ws = new WebSocket('wss://api.example.com/websocket');
ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer'
```

And I am printing the incoming data out using:

```
ws.onmessage = (message) => {
  console.log(message.data);
};
```

And the result looks something like this:

```
ArrayBuffer(76) {
  [[Int8Array]], [[Int16Array]], [[Int32Array]], [[UInt8Array]]
}
```

And the documentation of the API I am using says the following is what I will be seeing, which is not what I am currently seeing:

```
{
  "market": "United States",
  "current_price": 645.00000000,
  "highest_price": 887.00000000,
  ...
}
```

How do I convert this incoming data into JSON, or any form that I can use to display on my web application? I have tried things like `const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(message.data));` and this returns empty objects.

I have been stuck on this error for days now, can anyone please help?

Thank you!

Comment: did you read data from file?

Comment: @DaniilLoban no, I did not use any files here. Just getting the data from the WebSocket server and trying to convert the data. Do I need to use a file?

Comment: No, you don't, I just thought it was an error due to incorrect reading of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was the WebSocket library I was using.

I was using the 'ws' library, and it seems it cannot recognise data converted via .binaryType.

Once I removed the library and use the original WebSocket that Node.js provides, everything is good to go.

I appreciate everyone's try helping me.

Answer (score 2):

I had check your code. But can't get your output

my server code is:

```
const WebSocketServer = new require('ws');
let webSocketServer; 
const initServer = async() => {
    let port = 8091;
    webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer.Server({ port });
    webSocketServer.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
    console.log(`Server start on port: ${port}`)
    webSocketServer.on('connection', function(ws) {
        ws.send(
            JSON.stringify({
                "market": "United States",
                "current_price": 645.00000000,
                "highest_price": 887.00000000,
            }),
        )
    });
}

initServer();
```

and client code is:

```
<script>
  const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8091");
  ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
  ws.onmessage = function(message){ 
    console.log(JSON.parse(message.data));
  }
</script>
```

output is object:

[image: screenshot]

if you read data from json file try this code:

```
  const readData = (path) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function(err, contents) {
        if (!err)  resolve(JSON.parse(contents))
        else reject(Error(`The fail "${path}" is not read`))
      });
    });  
  }
```

also try this function:

```
const arrayBufferToString(buf) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it turns out that the library I was using is the problem. Everything is good now. I appreciate your reply tho!

Answer (score 1):

The `JSON.parse()` method is only able to parse a JSON string and not an ArrayBuffer. In order to work with a JSON string, you must use `JSON.stringify()` and stringify `message.data` as such: `data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(message.data);`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I did not mention it on my post but I also tried it, and it is also returning empty objects.